# Causing a flex-item to fill the entire practical width of a center-justified flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am attempting to divide a set of icons by the year they were created, but I only want the divider line to extend to the edges of the content (the blue squares).

The issue here is that I want this to work regardless of viewport size, as to keep it responsive. How can I make this divider element act the way I am describing?

```css
#parent{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.divider{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="divider">2020</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: always 3 element to divide after?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, the amount of elements in a row changes based on the viewport. It could be 1, it could be all of them.

Comment: I meant the number of item in the html, is it something known or not?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, a new icon is added every week

Comment: display: flex will result in the component you apply it to taking up 100% of available width. If the body is the direct parent of the display: flex element, that flex element (in this case, the #parent) will take up 100% of the width of the body. This comment isn't to give a solution, just to let you know why this is happening while I think about it.

Comment: @ssbrear I'm aware but thank you anyways. A good theoretical way to attain what I am trying to do is make the container a fixed width and apply `justify-content: center` and `justify-content space-between` at the same time. There is another stack question about this topic but the answer only works in a very specific circumstance.

Comment: ***but I only want the divider line to extend to the edges of the content (the blue squares).***  `edges of the content` does that mean you want there to be no margin/padding between the red border and the following `blue content` div/s

Comment: @dalelandry it means that I do not want the divider element to extend any further to the left or right than the furthermost left and furthermost right blue boxes, so there is a clean flat line along the left and right of the content while still maintaining center alignment of flex items. As you can see in the snippet, the red line extends beyond the blue boxes bounds in both directions.

Comment: You could use JS to get the width of the elements in relation to the viewports break points and then style the divider using JS; three classes that change a class depending on viewport size, as it seems there are only three potential orientations with a 250px wide div with margin... three wide (250 + 10 + 250 + 10 + 250), two wide (250 + 10 + 250) and one wide (250).

Comment: @dalelandry that seems... clunky. There has to be a way to do this in vanilla CSS

Answer (score -2):

You could try wrapping a year into a container and assigning a border-bottom to that container. Due to the containers being direct children of the parent, and not the child anymore, I made changed the main axis of the flex-flow to compensate.

Edit: Included an :after selector to include the year at each border.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.child-container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.child-container:after {
  content: '2020';
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing the way it flows is not viable, as I don't want to change the entire design. If I were to design it this way I could just ditch the flexbox to begin with and put them all in a fixed width box a-la instagram.